# Is it Possible to add mvcforum project to exisiting asp.net mvc5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source, asp.net-mvc-5, forum

I was wondering **if it's possible** to add [**MvcForum**](http://www.mvcforum.com/) [source code project](https://github.com/leen3o/mvcforum) to my existing Asp.Net Mvc5 Project plus compile and publish the whole project later?
I Wanted to add a **free open source forum** to my project, It will be cool and will save me a huge amount of development time.
If it's possible please tell me how, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What do you add?

Like integrate the codes of MvcForum or use it as a template?

Either way you can do it because it is open source, you can grab the code in GitHub
with the links you provided.

or if you want to put in a separate project within the same namespace

just right click your Namespace and you can add another existing project

Comment: I want to integrate the codes, put it as a module to my asp.net mvc web application which will be a content management system, add existing project to the solution is not gonna help

Comment: You can do that I guess, but there is no tool to make it automatic. You need to manually add the files to be integrated to your project